# Server side spam software for Window servers

Tags: windows, email, spam

Is there any 3rd party software that you can install on your Windows server that filters spam from your mail server? (Before the user downloads via POP3.)

Comment: Are you using Exchange? What version of Windows? What are you using to retrieve the POP3 messages?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Exchange 2007, anti spam filters are applied to emails that are downloaded via the POP3 connector. Of course, the connection filter is not applied and thus Exchange's built-in RBL feature is useless for emails retrieved via POP3.

However, you may want to look into a third part POP3 connector that includes anti spam (and can use RBLs for determining spam). For instance, the [POPCon Pro connector](http://www.christensen-software.com/popconpro/feature/antispam.htm) has anti spam and antivirus rolled into the POP3 connector. I believe that [ARX POP3 Connector](http://www.archimatrix.com/index.html?http://www.archimatrix.com/us/software/arxConnector/index.htm) also does SPAM filtering.

Comment: Filtering spam at the POP-download point isn't really the best solution. You should be filtering it as it hits the server via SMTP regardless of how your users later access the mail (POP, IMAP, OWA, RPC over HTTPS).

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for a software solution - however if you have any interest in an appliance solution I've found Barracuda Spam Firewalls are excellent products.  I am sure there are others out there as well, these are just the ones I've had experience with:  http://www.barracudanetworks.com/ns/products/spam_overview.php

It integrates with AD or LDAP, Exchange and filters all incoming mail for spam, viruses, etc and you can set the levels.  It can work as a relay and just pass the mail right through to your mail server after scanning.

Answer (score 0):

I have about 10 different clients utilizing different versions of [GFI Mail Essentials](http://www.gfi.com/mes/) with good success.  the software does include a pop3 connector called pop2exchange that works great as well.